# Перевод экспоненциальной записи числа в обычную

Tags: python-3.x

Есть такая конструкция

```
return 'Current price: ' + str(resBTC_obj['token']['last'])+ ' per 1 token'
```

Которая возвращается цену, но она возвращает цену в эксопненциальной форме, как избавиться от этого?

Comment: У вас в выводе функцией `print` экспоненциальная запись получается?

Comment: Нет, выводит нормально, но как добиться подобного без принта? Вот как выглядит вся строка text = address_text%(message.text, price, (round(float(message.text)*price,6), address1)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, где `.2f` - 2 знака после запятой:

```
'Current price: ' + '{:.2f}'.format(resBTC_obj['token']['last']) + ' per 1 token'
```